# Записать условие, которое является истинным, когда точка с координатами (x, y) попадает в заштрихованные участки

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Записать условие, которое является истинным, когда точка с координатами (x, y) попадает в заштрихованные участки.
Вот мои попытки кода но работает он не корректно,скорее всего ошибка в строке
`if (((x <= 1) && (y <= 1))||((x>=-1)&&(y>=-1)))`  но не понимаю что не так

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    int x, y;
    cout << "Введіть х" << endl;
    cin >> x;

    cout << "Введіть y" << endl;
    cin >> y;
    if (((x <= 1) && (y <= 1))||((x>=-1)&&(y>=-1))) {
        cout << "умова істина" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "умова хибна" << endl;
    }

 

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Во-первых, вставьте картинку в вопрос. Во-вторых, давайте рассмотрим, например, точку (1,1) - по вашей формуле она годится ("условие истинное") - а на рисунке? Давайте вы для начала запишете условия того, что точка попадает в треугольник - т.е. правее линии x= 0, выше линии y=0 и ниже линии y = 1-x. Это первое задание (поймите, написать **за вас** не проблема, но ведь надо же, чтобы вы научились писать сами...) Потом можете сразу написать второе условие - для квадрата. У вас же получается, что любая точка, координаты которой положительны, вас устраивает - ибо x>=-1, y>=-1 выполнены...

Comment: Да ошибка именно в той строке. Она проверяет совсем не то. Два примера: 1. x = 10,  y = 10. 2. x = -10, y = -10

Comment: Во-первых, сдесь явно нужно использовать float, а не int. Во-вторых, учитывая что у вас имеется такая фигура как треугольник, вы не можете просто сравнить координаты x, y с константными значениями (у вас же треугольник). Сдесь нужно уточнить: заштрихованная обрасть может изменяться или она константная - от этого зависит насколько простое решение у этой задачи

Answer (score 2):

Учитывая размеры заштрихованных областей, можно предположить, что входные данные являются числами с плавающей точкой. Поэтому необходимо объявить переменные `x` и `y` с соответствующим типом. Например, `double`:

```
double x, y;
```

Проверяем принадлежность точки `(x, y)` квадрату:

```
bool in_square = (-1 <= x && x <= 0) && (-1 <= y && y <= 0);
```

Проверяем принадлежность точки `(x, y)` треугольнику:

```
bool in_triangle = x >= 0 && y >= 0 && y <= 1 - x;
```

Проверяем, находится ли точка в закрашенной области:

```
bool result = in_square || in_triangle;
```